# maven dependency unable to read lib from the dependency jar

Tags: maven-2

I have projects A & B where Project B is dependent on A. When I run `mvn clean install` in the command prompt, Project A compiles well and it produces the dependent jar for Project B in the maven local repository. During the compilation of Project B, I am getting a  compilation error for a dependency listed in project B's POM. I have checked the classpath, versions and they are fine. The error I am seeing is mentioned below:

Project A

```
[INFO] Building tsscommon-ifc
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean]
[INFO] Deleting directory V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-ifc\target
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Compiling 455 source files to V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-ifc\target\classes
[INFO] [resources:testResources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] [surefire:test]
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [jar:jar]
[INFO] Building jar: V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-ifc\target
\tsscommon-ifc-2.39.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [install:install]
[INFO] Installing V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-ifc\target\tsscommon-ifc-2.39.00-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Documents and Settings\pwvxd35\.m2\repository\us\mn\state\dhs\tss\common\tsscommon-ifc\2.39.00-SNAPSHOT\tsscommon-ifc-2.39.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is fine.

Project B

```
[INFO] Building tsscommon-server
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean]
[INFO] Deleting directory V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-server\target
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Compiling 137 source files to V:\dhs_tss_build_view\dhs_tssproject\tss\tsscommon-server\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
V:/dhs_tss_build_view/dhs_tssproject/tss/tsscommon-server/src/main/java/us/mn/state/dhs/tss/common/oblix/da/wsdl/OblixLoginAccess.java:[51,60] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BusinessException
location: class us.mn.state.dhs.tss.common.oblix.da.wsdl.OblixLoginAccess
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Please format the mvn output as code so it's easier to read.

Comment: sorry for that, i formated now u can have clear visual

Comment: He means to use the formatting tools of the StackOverflow editor. I've fixed this for you.

Comment: Please show us both POMs. Is OblixLoginAccess generated from a WSDL? Perhaps its not getting packaged up into the JAR.

Comment: thank you, I am new to this website forgive me i am not aware of the features it has
packages is generated in the jar, i can see them by navigating manually

Comment: you don't need to ask 3 time the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589121/maven-compilation-failure
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588952/maven-dependency-problem-compilation-error

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
OblixLoginAccess.java:[51,60] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BusinessException
location: class us.mn.state.dhs.tss.common.oblix.da.wsdl.OblixLoginAccess
```

This simply means that there is a class `BusinessException` referenced in the code for `OblixLoginAccess` at line `51`, character `60`.

The symbol cannot be found on the compile classpath.

This may or may not have anything to do with dependencies of Project B on Project A. You need to find out where that class is supposed to be, and make sure it is there.