# Jenkins org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins to build up a Maven project, and I'm getting the following error, which I have no clue how to solve.  I have spent an entire day searching through Google and here, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance for your help and guidance.

---

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/Java_1.6.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.

**loads of other INFO and Debug logs**

[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project web-platform3: Compilation failure
cause : Compilation failure
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project web-platform3: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Have you tried to run Maven with `-X` to get more details about the failure?  Are you able to try tu use a more recent version of `maven-compiler-plugin`, like 2.5.1?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt replyThat is using -X.
I will try 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

> Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>
> Java home: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/Java_1.6.0/jre

This looks strange. Are you sure this is correct? Maybe try to use the same version.

Comment: Hi, I've changed it back to 1.7 now but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `JAVA_HOME` should not point to the `jre` folder. Try with

```
JAVA_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/Java_1.7.0_04/
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a description for this under this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17683183/1068938

In most of the cases it is a UTF-8 conversion problem

I hope it will help you.