# mvn clean install not able to resolve class

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have the following maven structure

```
parent POM.XML
 - common/pom.xml
 - search/pom.xml
```

Search module is not able to get `common` module classes when i do mvn clean install on `search` module
I get `package de.test.common does not exists`. I even ran `mvn clean install` on parent platform but no success. `common` module is building fine.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.test.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>search</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.test.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <app-name>search</app-name>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.test.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>searchdev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>searchprod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <appName>${app-name}</appName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

common pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.test.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.test.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <app-name>common</app-name>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>commondev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>commonprod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <appName>${app-name}</appName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

[image]

I think i have the same problem mentioned here

[maven compilation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589121/maven-compilation-failure)

Found the problem but not the cause

***I removed the following dependency and everything is okay***

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
```

after removing the plugin the jar is build in a different structure. When spring boot plugin was there the whole content was inside BOOT-INF folder which i think was the cause, not sure though... need expert opinion here.

Comment: have you installed 'common' module (to your local repository - mvn   clean install )

Comment: yes i have the jar under \.m2\repository\de\test\common\common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: paste the pom of "common"...

Comment: pasted sir. Plase have a look.

Comment: bit strange i just ran with above same setup mvn clean install run fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. May be somebody will find it useful.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: What it does is appending the specified classifier at the end of Spring Boot Jar while keeping the non-Boot Jar as is. This way the dependent module can get its dependency. Spring Boot Jar is repackaged in a way that the dependent module cannot load a repackaged jar's classes.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is through a so called reactor project, where you build all dependent modules with the parent pom. To that end, add the following code to your parent POM:

```
<modules>
  <module>common</module>
  <module>search</module>
</modules>
```

Now, build the parent pPOM and your entire build should work.
Also, don't use explicit versions in the child projects, only inherit the version from the parent POM (I think you're good there). If you reference dependencies from the same project reactor, use the version `${project.version}`.

Comment: I have already the snippet defined in the parent POM and the worse part is the parent pom build is breaking in search module complaning that common module is not there ....

Comment: updated the reactor console ... it always breaks at the project which imports common module.

Comment: see updated. The spring boot plugin was causing issues. Dont know why.